# Document Storage That Works Well with Grails

Tags: grails, content-management-system, document

We need to manage various documents and files in our Grails application.  Is there anything out there that integrates well with Grails that is specifically document management and not a full CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at JCR (Java Content Repository) implementations? On a past Java (not grails/groovy) project, I had a lot of success with [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/).

However, it surprises me that the grails plugin support for JCR and/or Jackrabbit seems somewhat immature and uncompleted at this time. If you're interested, perhaps we could partner and write something together for this.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  I'll take a look at that.  I was kind of hoping for something a bit more "ready-made".

Comment: Marking this as the answer mainly because no one else has tried to answer.